# Concurrency when calling webservice clients

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws

I have a webapp that use some webservice clients to get the data it displays.

When the load is not very high the app work just fine.

Unfortunately when the load is bigger the servers become overloaded because of 
the following stucked threads...

Any idea what might be the cause ?

```
]", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
    com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.Catalog.parseCatalog(Catalog.java:660)
    com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.createDefaultCatalogResolver(XmlUtil.java:251)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:265)
    com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:228)
    weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSServiceDelegate.java:52)
    weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSProvider.java:371)
    weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:79)
    weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:62)
    javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the service client is timing out parsing the WSDL.

Ensure that the WSDL and any dependencies it imports are being loaded locally and not being fetched over the network from the service host. You can provide the path to a local WSDL via a [constructor that takes a URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#Service%28java.net.URL,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29); you will still have to inspect your WSDL to ensure that any schemas it imports are referred to by relative URIs.

Also ensure that you reuse your [`Service`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html) instances by making them application scope. Since parsing the WSDL is expensive, you want to do this as seldom as possible. Check that your JAX-WS implementation's `Service` is threadsafe (I'm not aware of an implementation where they aren't but it pays to check). The [ports](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#createDispatch%28javax.xml.namespace.QName,%20java.lang.Class,%20javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode%29) the services create vary - in some implementations, these are threadsafe; in some they aren't.

Comment: Apparently the JAX WS is not thread safe and this is the big problem...I have to build a pool of webservices clients .Do you know anything that already does something similar ? Thanks for the response

Comment: @Cris - Ah, I've never used WebLogic; other implementations do better. I am not aware of any ready-made solutions.

Comment: Weblogic's JAX-WS port objects are threadsafe as long as you don't modify the PORT's context in any way. once you need to modify the context you have to create a new port per thread or create a pool of port objects. typically for weblogic's (10.3.3) JAX-WS implementation, I use an application scoped Service object and a threadlocal to store port instances -- this works out well using the factory pattern with threadlocal's initial value factory. in this way the code only has to parse the wsdl once and you get to do whatever you want with the port object.